# Screen scaper that follows redirects and encodes to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, screen-scraping, rubygems

I'm looking for a gem (or a combination of gems) that can, given an URL, return the page content as UTF-8. It should also follow redirects if the URL is changed.

Does anyone know of such?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)? It seems to do what you are looking for in terms of encoding:

> ENCODING:
>
> Strings are always stored as UTF-8
>   internally. Methods that return text
>   values will always return UTF-8
>   encoded strings. Methods that return
>   XML (like to_xml, to_html and
>   inner_html) will return a string
>   encoded like the source document.

You can also automate some of your screen scraping with [Mechanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize) (click links, submit forms, etc). Mechanize builds on Nokogiri so it's a nice complement to it.

Some webcasts you may want to look at:

- Nokogiri:
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri
- Mechanize:
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize

Comment: N/m. I found Event machine (https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/) which did the job!